# Problem of lens distance - Geometrical optics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, geometric-optics, lenses

I'm study geometrical optics and I'm doing an exercise which says:

To the left of a thin lens an object is located at a distance p in various positions, indicated in the table. For each of the positions of the object, the distance from the image to the lens (q in the table) and its location to the right (r) or left (l) of the lens are determined. Distances are expressed in cm and were measured with a ruler graduated to mm.

[image]

a) Make a ray diagram that illustrates the situation described for the first pair of values.

b) Determine the focal length of the lens (use whichever method is most convenient for you) using the three measurements provided.

For my resolution i used the focal distance formula: $\frac{1}{F}=\frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{s'}$

Resolving:

**Position 1**

$p=5 | q=10,2$ (left)

$\frac{1}{F} = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{10,2}$

$\frac{1}{F} = 0,298$

$F = \frac{1}{0,298}$

$F = 3,355$

[image]

**Position 2**

$p=15 | q=30,2$ (right)

$\frac{1}{F} = \frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{30,2}$

$\frac{1}{F} = 0,298$

$F = 0.099$

$F = 10,02$

[image]

**Position 3**

$p=20 | q=19,8$ (right)

$\frac{1}{F} = \frac{1}{20} + \frac{1}{19,8}$

$\frac{1}{F} = 0,1$

$F = \frac{1}{0,1}$

$F = 10$

[image]

But I'm not sure about the signs when the image is reflected at the right or at the left. Are these resolutions ok or do I have to correct something? Are graphics acceptable representations of the phenomenon or not?

Comment: What does "19.8 (d)" signify? Also, where is the mirror mentioned in the headline?

Comment: Sorry (d) was a misspelling, I edited it already, and rather it's of an exercises of lenses than mirrors. I think the mirror it's the lens that reflects image to the left.